# RoR validations -- conditions being ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I am trying to get a model to verify the uniqueness of a column WHEN two criteria are met -- published is true, and deprecated is false. If either of those things are opposite, don't save the model. **Right now, it seems to be preventing duplicates regardless of the values of these columns.**

I have a model:

```
Article
-------
name:string
description:string
value:string
value_hash:string
published:bool
deprecated:bool
```

Here is its class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :value
  validates_uniqueness_of :checksum, conditions: -> {where(published: true).where(deprecated: false)},  message: "already exists."
  before_save :hash_article_value

  def hash_article_value
    self.checksum = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.value)
  end

end
```

So, if Joe saves an article, and its not published, then Mike saves the same article and publishes it, it should allow Mike to do so. Joe would then try to publish the same article and it would fail the uniqueness constraint.

The issue:
Right now, if Joe saves an unpublished article, Mike cannot publish the exact same article (fails the uniqueness constraint).

**Why does it fail when I specify conditions in the validates_uniqueness_of ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you calculate your `checksum` using `before_save` callback, so you have `nil` checksum while run validations. use `before_validate` callback